# DynamoDB with Cognito limitations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement a public file sharing system for my application using AWS Cognito & DynamoDB. Basically users can create and sign into an account using Cognito and use this account to upload their files. Public meta data that needs to be accessed frequently goes to DynamoDB (such as ratings, download count, upload date, etc.) and the files itself to an S3 bucket.

To ensure that only the Cognito user who shared the file is allowed to delete the DynamoDB item and modify certain private attributes, I am using the Cognito identity id as the primary key for my items inside the DynamoDB, coupled with a policy rule [as described in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_rows.html). Afaik there is no other solution.

So far so good, but this obviously means that a user cannot upload more than 1 item to the database since the primary key attributes of DynamoDB items need to be unique, which is not possible since I am using the Cognito identity id for them.

I could of course create one item for each user and store the meta data for each file he owns inside maps, but this wouldn't allow me to query the items by date, rating, etc.

I'm honestly stuck and cannot think of a way to structure my database items any other way to make this work. Is this even feasible with DynamoDB?

Comment: Did you look into adding a range key as a guid for each image, while keeping primary key as cognito id?

Comment: @Ashan Thank you very much, that actually worked. I recreated the table and added a sort key on setup.

Comment: No probs. I have updated the answer for others future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a range key with a unique id for each file, while maintaining the primary key as Cognito id which allows to keep the DynamoDB fine-grained authorization.